# The intersection of $3$ set is empty, would the intersection of $4$ sets be empty?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let me clarify some more.

Let's say we have four sets $A,B,C,$ and $D$.

If the intersection of any three sets is empty, by default is the intersection of all four sets empty?

Comment: As shown in the answers, you need only that the intersection of *some* subcollection of $\{A, B, C, D\}$ is empty, since $A \cap B \cap C \cap D$ is a subset of any such intersection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Let's suppose that $A \cap B \cap C = \emptyset$. Then $A \cap B \cap C \cap D = (A \cap B \cap C) \cap D = \emptyset \cap D = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ are sets such that the intersection of any three is empty, then because intersection is *associative*, we have that $A \cap B \cap C \cap D = (A \cap B \cap C) \cap D = \emptyset \cap D = \emptyset$.

Just in case you aren't sure what associative means, it means that we can intersect in any order.  So, in the case of three sets, we get $(A \cap B) \cap C = A \cap (B \cap C)$.  In the case of four sets intersected, you can intersect them in any order you want.

Answer (score 2):

$A \cap B \cap C \cap D \subseteq A \cap B \cap C = \emptyset$. Thus $A \cap B \cap C \cap D = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. $A\cap B\cap C\cap D=A\cap B\cap(C\cap D)$ is the intersection of the three sets $A$ and $B$ and $C\cap D$, so it is empty.